# Increase invoke Response payload size in AWS Lambda to 15 mb

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

As per current implementation by AWS, the response payload size returned by a Lambda function cannot exceed `6 mb`. Is there a provision for increasing this limit to `15 mb` by requesting a "Service Limit Increase". Also, what are the additional charges, if any that would be charged?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10):

no.

But you can upload the result to S3 and return the s3 bucket name + key so the caller of the Lambda can download the result from S3 which can handle files of that size without any issues.

Comment: Never take no for an answer.

Answer (score 3):

AWS just released response payload streaming [link](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/04/aws-lambda-response-payload-streaming/)

Response streaming allows you to send responses larger than Lambda’s 6 MB response payload limit up to a soft limit of 20 MB.

[more here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-aws-lambda-response-streaming/)

Comment: Worth noting that: "Lambda supports response streaming only on `Node.js 14.x`, `Node.js 16.x`, and `Node.js 18.x` managed runtimes." ([source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-response-streaming.html))